# Is it possible for a domain owner to enable Google Drive API for all users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've added a few scripts to a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/). One uses the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/). First time a person runs the script he has to manuallly enable access to [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/) and click on the link to [Google Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/) and enable access to Drive API.

There are about 100 people in my organisation who are going to use this spreadsheet and is there some way for me as a domain owner to enable Drive API so that the users don't have to do it by themselves?

/Magnus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users are going to have to create there own application in Google Developers console, and authenticate themselves.

Google Made a [change](http://www.daimto.com/changes-to-the-google-apis-terms-of-service/) recently that makes it against terms of service for you as a developer to give out your client id from Google developer console.  So they will need to make there own.  There is also no API that will let you automate this for them either.

As for authenticating that is the nature of authentication.  Each user must give the application /or in this case script access to there account.

Sounds like you are doing everything correctly right now.   It may seam time consuming but that is the way things have to be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What seems to work is that I share the spreadsheet to all users. The make a copy of the file and it gets stored in their drive.

Then they run the script and the authenticate. Next they will have to go Tools -> Script Editor - Resources -> Advanced Google Services and enable Drive API, then into Google Developer Console and enable Drive API. Am I right? 

Luckily we are a IT consultant company so I guess this won't be a big deal.